How to render HTML in a PrimeFaces <p:selectOneMenu> with f:selectItems and avoid displaying raw HTML?
Description:
I am trying to render HTML content inside a PrimeFaces <p:selectOneMenu> by using f:selectItems. Specifically, I want to display a color box along with a description for each item in the dropdown. However, instead of rendering the HTML correctly, it is displaying the raw HTML code as plain text, including attribute paths and class names.
Here is the code I am working with:
Java (Managed Bean):
public String coresComHtml(Cor cor) {

    if (cor == null) {
        return "";
    }

    String html = String.format(
            "<div style='display: flex; align-items: center;'>"
                    + "<div style='width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: %s; border: 1px solid #000; margin-right: 5px;'></div>"
                    + "<span>%s</span>"
                    + "</div>",
            cor.getHexadecimal(), cor.getDescricao());

    return html;
}

XHTML:
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p:outputLabel value="Código da Cor"  
                        for="codigo_da_cor" />

        <p:selectOneMenu id="codigo_da_cor" 
                            value="#{MB.dataView.entidade.idCor}" 
                            styleClass="width100"
                            label="#{sessionMB.getLabelObservacao('label_cor')}">
            
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
            
            <f:selectItems value="#{MB.dataView.cores}" 
                            var="item" 
                            itemValue="#{item.id}">

                <f:facet name="itemLabel">
                    <h:outputText value="#{MB.dataView.coresComHtml(item)}" 
                                    escape="false" />
                </f:facet>
            </f:selectItems>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
</div>


Problem:
Instead of rendering the HTML as intended (a color box and description), the browser is displaying the raw HTML code, including the class names and attribute paths.
I've tried various approaches, such as using escape="false", but I still can't get it to render properly.
What I have tried:
I’ve tried using escape="false" in the h:outputText tag to allow HTML rendering, but the output still shows the HTML as raw text.
I also checked if the HTML string is correct, and it is.
Can anyone guide me on how to properly render the HTML content within the <p:selectOneMenu> dropdown so that it displays as a color box with text next to it, instead of displaying the raw HTML?

Why are you trying to render html inside a component though? This looks like an XY Problem Rather than trying solve something you think it is the right solution, what is the problem you are trying to solve in the first place? The html you are trying to add to the component seems simple enough that the component itself could be configured to achieve it?

Thanks for your reply! I understand that rendering HTML inside a component might not be the best approach, but I've tried several different solutions and the problem still persists. What I need is to display the color name along with a small color box next to it in each dropdown option.
I haven’t found a better way to achieve this within the <p:selectOneMenu>. If you have any suggestions or ideas on how to solve this, I would really appreciate your hel

Terrible idea indeed. HTML code doesn't belong in model, it belongs in view. Use custom content with p:column. See "Advanced" and "Icons" examples in the p:selectOneMenu showcase page https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml. Inline styles are also a terrible idea but alas.
